# Navigation position

Tags: navigation, design, organization

I'm re-rethinking my website and I would like to know what's the best for users.

1. A navigation centered on the page + a centered logo
2. A navigation on the left or right with a logo on the opposite (like most of the website we find

I was thinking about #1 could be original, but I'm not sure that could work with a Portfolio, because a centered logo is acting to seperate two differents sections the navigation like work on the left and social stuffs on the right. But I could also put the logo centered on top and navigation at the bottom and centered... It look like restaurants no?

Almost everyone use #2 on the portfolio...

I thought about a diagonal navigation, but I think it's a bit weird and hard to do. I changed my mind to maybe make like choice #4 in image bellow for "fixed" navigation. I think I will keep choice #3 for "normal" navigation, but it's not matching my idea for "fixed" navigation.

Another concern I have about navigation and probably about the centered logo seperating two sections is my nav organization.
That's the section I have; Home, About, Work, Photography, Contact and maybe Blog.
I don't really know if I should keep this order or put About section before Contact.

Also, my work section (my website will be single page) will have a link to see archive (more works), so I don't know if my Portfolio link in my navigation should be linked to the id or to the other page (archive)?

[image: Navigation design idea]

EDIT : I re-thought about centered logo and I think it's a bad idea if you want to add more section. It will be unbalanced like 2 nav on the left and 3 on the right. So I will keep a normal navigation, but will try to design it well.

Comment: Will it be a static or fixed navigation?

Comment: Static on top of the page, but will change to fixed when scroll down section 1. I added a couple of ideas. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If your portfolio is going to target tech savvy and creative people, I guess its ok to go experimental. A diagonal or a more unique approach would impress this group of user. However if you intend to show your website to a broader group of users, you might want to tread on the safe side. A more conventional layout such as layout 3 would appeal to them and makes it easy for them to comprehend your site. Especially if you are going to showcase work that are related to UX and less of aesthetic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I remove my small triangle idea, because I think it's a bit weird and maybe too hard to do.
So I though about a smooth triangle with the nav and centered logo. I just want to be original with my portfolio.